# Merge rows with same fields with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataset, jupyter

I have a books CSV dataset, with Book-Title, ISBN, Author, Publisher and year of publication columns. In my dataset are some redundant rows so I want to merge the rows sharing the same Book-Title, Author and publisher. I want to merge them in a new dataset and don't show the books that have not been merged.
Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

Hello that may helps you :

```
books_df = pd.read_csv('books.csv') 
books_df_new = books_df.iloc[books_df [['author','title','publisher']].drop_duplicates().index]
```

You can reset index also with using `books_df_new.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `drop_duplicates` method to remove the duplicates.

```py
books = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
books_new = books.drop_duplicates(["Book-Title", "Author", "publisher"])
```